# Can X, Y co-ordinates be scaled so they're independent of change of Z in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, math, graphics, 3d, formula

I wanted to know if X, Y co-ordinates in OpenGL can be scaled such that any change to Z can be countered.

I've found [one link that talks about this possibility](https://cycling74.com/forums/opengl-how-to-scale-xy-so-that-it-is-independent-of-z).

Although, it doesn't look like they found an answer.
I'm using Frustum perspective for drawing.

I'd like to know if there's any way this can be done, and if there's a formula that can do this.

Comment: So [billboarding](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/)?

Comment: OpenGL uses rectilinear projection which means that surfaces of constant Z are *planes* perpendicular to the camera direction. Thus any changes in the world coordinates have to be constrained to such a plane.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do? It sounds like you just don't want a perspective transform.